# Logo Feedback Please!

Tags: logo, critique

[image]

I really need feedback on my logo. I am in the process of branding my Great- Grandmother's Pie's for my portfolio, but I do not want to proceed until I complete the logo.

Comment: Do you have anything better than this badly scanned and cut out photo? It does not present your great-grandmother very well.

Comment: Hello @Myranda, welcome to GDSE. Please refer to our [critique guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/682#682) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I agree with Rad Lexus. Very bad photo. No offense, but I'd start completely over. After researching logo design. Especially fonts; the script font here makes "Pies" look like "Dies" or "Lies". So, new font, new colors, different graphic, etc.

Comment: I do have a regular picture of this without that filter.  Actually trying to figure out how to upload it now. Do you think I should just leave out her face all together? I've been so stuck on this "design" that I haven't tried to come up with anything else. #VeryFrustrated!

Comment: you should also try an icon like this http://bit.ly/2agQ4gI on iconfinder instead of the actual picture...and take some inspiration from this logo http://bit.ly/2aE6DGU...take a look at other round logos too...You should create a vector logo for the cleanliness

Answer (score 1):

perhaps try without the photo, as it will date the look of the logo quickly and not work as effectively when used on smaller applications. A nice typography crest logo with a pie icon/silhouette (originally drawn of course) would work really nicely and your Grandmas photo could be used on additional design pieces such as flyers etc.